# does couchbase syncgateway support login with access_token instead of id_token?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a pair of questions:

1. Does `syncgateway` support login with access token instead of `idtoken`
2. Does `syncgateway` support defined roles in a token?

Answer (score 1):

Does Sync Gateway support login with access token instead of ID Token?

> No. Sync Gateway only supports ID Token for OpenID Connect
> Authentication. ID tokens are JSON web tokens (JWTs). Each token
> contains information for the intended audience (which is usually the
> recipient). According to the OpenID Connect specification, the
> audience of the ID token (indicated by the aud claim) must be the
> client ID of the application making the authentication request. If
> this is not the case, you should not trust the token. In general, it
> is not preferable to use Access tokens for authentication because
> Access tokens cannot tell if the user has authenticated.

Does Sync Gateway support defined roles in a token?

> No. Sync Gateway doesn’t support roles to be defined in the
> authentication token. Roles have a separate namespace from users; it
> is generally recommended to use the Admin REST API for assigning roles
> to users.

If you are interested in knowing more about authentication and roles, here is the official documentation:

1. [Users and Roles](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/users-and-roles.html)
2. [Authentication](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/authentication.html)